Не работает ClickDetector держа в руках инструмент с моделью
Почему, когда я нажимаю на ClickDetector (в объекте), держа в руках инструмент с моделью (с Handle), при клике ничего не происходит а без Handle все работает? И как это исправить
local clickDetector = script.Parent.Parent.ClickDetector

clickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    print(player.Name .. " кликнул по объекту!")
end)


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
